# How gradient descent algorithm behaves when it doesn't reach minimum

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Sorry for this ugly image. When the gradient descent algorithm reaches the coefficient value where the error is minimal as shown in the figure, how does the algorithm move forward to reach the global minimum? I am new to Machine Learning. Please bear with me for such a very basic question.

[image]

Comment: What you illustrate is a well-known issue with simple gradient descent methods -- they get stuck at local minima.  SO's format of short snappy questions with nice crisp answers is not a good fit for what you need to learn now, hit the Internet with your favourite search engine.  SO isn't the place, either, as I'm sure you know, to ask for recommendations for offset resources.

Comment: Agreed!!. Thank you. :)

Comment: In my previous comment *offset resources* should have been *off-site resources*.  Damm ortokorrection.